# Click to open Jquery UI tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery and [jquery UI](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js) for tabs.I want to open Translation tab on save button click
[image]

```
<div id="dialog3" class="window">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Translation</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1" style="overflow:auto ; height:375px">
            <p>Information</p>
        </div>
         <div id="tabs-2" style="overflow:auto ; height:375px">
            <p>Translation</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) options to set it in the save click handler

```
$( "#dialog3" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

In the simple way just trigger the click event to #tabs-2 (is simulate the click to #tabs-2)

```
$('a[href="#tabs-2"]').click();
```

or this, if you have many dialog of tabs

```
$('#dialog3 a[href="#tabs-2"]').click();
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#dialog3" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
```

reference **[active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

For reference [check this](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with: `$("#dialog3").tabs("select", 1);`

Function to get Proper tab index:

```
function GetTabIndexByID(tabsDivId, searchedId) {
    var index = -1;
    var i = 0, els = $("#" + tabsDivId).find("ul a");
    var l = els.length, e;
    while (i < l && index == -1) {
        e = els[i];
        if (searchedId == e.id) {
            index = i;
        }
        i++;
    };

    return index;
}
```

Usage : `GetTabIndexByID('dialog3', 'tab2')`

IMP: Give id to your `<a href="#tabs-1" id="tab1" />`

Finally: `$("#dialog3").tabs("select", Number(GetTabIndexByID('dialog3', 'tab2')));`

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NuhFa/